# Spring automatic default definition of beans (without component scan)

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, guice

To reduce the amount of boilerplate in my Spring configurations (without using component-scan or the like), I'd like to run Spring in a Guice-like mode with "convention over configuration".

In Guice, you don't need to explictly configure a bean. I can create a bean structure like the following and Guice will "do the right thing":

```
class Foo {
  @Inject
  public Foo(Bar bar) {
  }
}

class Bar {
  @Inject
  public Bar(Blah blah) {
  }
}

class Blah {
  public Blah() {}
}
```

In Spring, I would need to have an associated `@Configuration` class that would just be full of boilerplate like so:

```
class Config {
  @Bean public void foo() {
    return new Foo();
  }

  // etc.
}
```

I suspect that this might be possible with a custom BeanFactory, but I'd like to avoid having to go down that road if this is possible through some other means in Spring.

`@ComponentScan` would be an alternative, but I want this to work with objects outside of my control that don't have the appropriate spring `@Component` annotation, and I'd prefer to use more of a scalpel approach than the shotgun of component scanning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've pretty much nailed it. You can have `<context:component-scan>` along with some further xml-based bean definitions for classes outside of your control. The Guice way would be to bind a `Provider` for these classes. Pick your poison. Recently I found myself trying to squeeze a bit more magic out of these DI frameworks too only to realize there's good reason why some things don't just work automatically. Would be dangerous if anything else.